# write object to file from servlet

Tags: java, file, exception, servlets

I'm trying to write to file from a servlet and i'm not really sure if the path i gave in the xml file is wrong or something else

```
    private List<User> getUsersList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    User u;
    while(true){
        if((u=(User) ois.readObject())==null)
            break;
        else{
            users.add(u);
        }
    }
    ois.close();
    return users;
}
```

that's the method i use to read from file where

```
private final String usersfile;
private ArrayList<User> users;
private File f;
public UsersService(String filename) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    super();
    usersfile=filename;
    f=new File(this.usersfile);
    if(!f.exists()){
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    users= (ArrayList<User>) this.getUsersList();

}
```

and the xml param

```
 <context-param>
<param-name>userslist</param-name>
<param-value>/users.txt</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and that's the exception

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at service.UsersService.getUsersList(UsersService.java:48)
at service.UsersService.<init>(UsersService.java:29)
at controller.LogServlet.doPost(LogServlet.java:43)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at controller.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: and closing tag for context - param

Comment: Where is /users.txt ? (In the root of your linux server?)

Comment: Yes you can pass the file in param value. your passing way doesn't have any problem...

Comment: i'm using windows. it's located in the root of the project

Comment: Where the file `(users.txt)` is located in application

Comment: well. it seems that's not the problem..i just gave the absolute path and i still get an exception at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hey, I think you are not giving the correct path where the file is located

Comment: **What is in your file?** A file named `.txt` is not usually a Java serialized object.

Comment: Yes. indeed. this was a part of my problem. (Trying to write serialized object in .txt)

Answer (score 0):

Here we say that if there aren't any more bytes to read then we should break out of the while loop before trying to read the object, etc.

```
 while (true) {
   if (ois.readObject() == -1) break;
   //...rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Now you can try with this...??

Comment: i edited the code.look above .i tried something like that because i can't test readObject()==-1. it returns an object